# How do I add multiple externalNativeBuild files to gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Using Android Studio, how can I add multiple externalNativeBuild files to my project (i.e. one CmakeLists.txt for my own C++ code and one .mk script for an external library)? The documentation says:

> Each module in your Android project can link to only one CMake or ndk-build script file

Comment: Each module… I take it that the restriction would not apply if you wrapped the external library into a module of its own, if doing so is a feasible option.